# Calculating in an array

Tags: java

I want to calculate an x and a y value in my coördinaat class. I've got another class called arrayreader which just reads a textfile and returns it.

```
public class Coordinaten
{  

    public static final double SCHERMBREEDTE = 1200;
    public static final double SCHERMHOOGTE = 1000;

    private double tMax, tMin, sMax, sMin;
    private Double[] ecgWaardes, xWaardes, yWaardes, coordinaatX;

    public Coordinaten()
    {
        ArrayReader ecg1 = new ArrayReader(); 
        ecg1.leesBestand();
        ecg1.getLijnen();
        ecgWaardes = ecg1.getLijnen();


    }

    public double bepaalTMax()
    /**
     * Deze method geeft de tijd in miliseconden van de ECG weer.
     */
    {
        tMax = (ecgWaardes.length * 2);
        return tMax;

    }

    public double bepaalSMax() 
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < ecgWaardes.length; i++)
        {
            sMax = ecgWaardes[0];
            if (ecgWaardes[i] > sMax)
            {
                sMax = ecgWaardes[i];
            }
        }
        return sMax;
    }

    public double bepaalSMin() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ecgWaardes.length; i++)
        {
            sMin = ecgWaardes[0];
            if (ecgWaardes[i] < sMin)
            {
                sMin = ecgWaardes[i];
            }
        }
        return sMin;
    }

    public Double[] berekenX()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ecgWaardes.length; i++)
        {
            coordinaatX = new Double[i]; 
            xWaardes [i] = (double)((((i+1) *2) - 0) * (SCHERMBREEDTE-1) / (tMax - 0));

        }
        return xWaardes;
    }

    public Double[] berekenY()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ecgWaardes.length; i++)
        {
            yWaardes = new Double[i]; 
            yWaardes [i] = (double)(((ecgWaardes[i] - sMax) * (SCHERMHOOGTE-1)) / (sMin - sMax));

        }
        return yWaardes;
    }
```

It just keeps giving me null pointer exceptions and i really don't know why?
Anyone who can help?

Comment: paste the stack trace

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint, for pointing out where the nullreference exception gets thrown.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Coordinaten.berekenX(Coordinaten.java:73)

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Coordinaten.berekenY(Coordinaten.java:84)

That is where it gives the errors

Comment: Why are you dealing with `Double[]` instead of `double[]`?

Comment: And again check your code you are casting your values to (double) instead of Double and again in future you will face ClassCastException too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialise yWaardes, xWaardes, ... you put the initialization in your for loop! This causes your array to be reinitialised and (and resized) every loop in the for! You should only initialise your arrays once! This can be done outside the for loop and by making it `ecgWaardes.length`:

```
public Double[] berekenY()
    {
        yWaardes = new Double[ecgWaardes.length]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < ecgWaardes.length; i++)
        {

            yWaardes [i] = (double)(((ecgWaardes[i] - sMax) * (SCHERMHOOGTE-1)) / (sMin - sMax));

        }
        return yWaardes;
    }
```

EDIT: Note that the above only is valid for the initialisation for yWaardes, simular mistakes can be found for the other arrays. So make sure all your arrays are properly initialised!